# Read subprocess stdout while maintaining it in the buffer

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Is it possible to read a subprocess's `stdout` but at the end of the program still maintain the whole `process.communicate()`?

For example i have a python script that starts a c# app in a `Popen` subprocess and checks the log file it produces live to determine the state it is in but certain errors are not dumped in the logs and are in the `stdout` and certain errors there will cause the process to hang. I want to be able to detect that output and in those cases be able to kill the process.

This is easy while doing `process.stdout.readline()` but at the end of the program i loose the ability to dump the entire stdout in it's native formatting  because the buffer get's flushed after reading. Is it possible to maintain that buffer?

Or at the very least save the read lines in a variable in it's native formatting?

Comment: You could save the lines you read to your own list. Depending on how you want to consume that data later, you've got the list or you could `b"".join(stdoutlist)` into a bytes string or even dump it into an `io` buffer to have a read method like the original stdout.

Comment: you mean something like this ? `io.BytesIO(b"some initial binary data: \x00\x01")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read stdout line by line, process it and save it to a list or buffer, and have the buffer available later. In this example processing is just `print`, but you could change that however you want. I also assumed you just want to collect stderr in the background, so created a separate thread.

```
import subprocess as subp
import threading
import io

def _pipe_read_thread(stream, output):
    output.write(stream.read())
    stream.close()

def proc_runner(cmd):
    stdout_lines = []
    stdout_buf = io.BytesIO()
    stderr_buf = io.BytesIO()
    p = subp.Popen(cmd, stdout=subp.PIPE, stderr=subp.PIPE)
    stderr_t = threading.Thread(target=_pipe_read_thread,
        args=(p.stderr, stderr_buf))
    stderr_t.start()
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line)
        stdout_buf.write(line)
    returncode = p.wait()
    stderr_t.join()
    stdout_buf. seek(0)
    stderr_buf.seek(0)
    return returncode, stdout_buf, stderr_buf

returncode, stdout, stderr = proc_runner(['ls', '-a'])
print('=============================')
print(stdout.read())
print('=============================')
print(stderr.read())
```